# Python: NameError: global name 'foobar' is not defined

Tags: python, namespaces, nameerror

I have written the following class:

```
class myClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def foo(self, arg1, arg2):
        pp = foobar(self, arg1, arg2)
        if pp:
            return 42
        else
            return -666


    def foobar(self, arg1, arg2):
        if arg1 == arg2:
            return 42
        else:
            return None
```

The logic is nonsensical - ignore it. What I am trying to so is to call an instance method from another instance method - and I am getting a `NameError`. I originally thought that this was due to `foo()` calling `foobar()` before it had been defined - but switching the order of the function definitions in the script made no difference.

Does anyone what's causing this error, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Python doesn't scope code to the local class automatically; you need to tell it to.

```
pp = self.foobar(arg1, arg2)
```

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: you mean : __pp = self.foobar(arg1, arg2)__ ?

Comment: @Glenn: Thanks. I suspected it was a scoping issue. Thanks for the link as well. time to RTFM I suppose!

Comment: singularity: Actually, you're right it should be self.foobar(arg1, arg2). Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @singularity: (Of course, though the link was more the point...)

Comment: @skyeagle:  Using 2.6.4 on Windows, I get a "TypeError: foobar() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)" if I use self.foobar(self,arg1, arg2).

Comment: adding `self` as first argument is actual for call parent class methods from child method

Comment: @seriyPS: Err, no.  That's what `super` is for.

Comment: @GreenMatt see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743673/python-typeerror-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given