# Python: TypeError: takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python

I'm currently using singpath.com to practice my python, but I face an issue with a problem:

The expected result is:

```
>>>CurryPuff(3) 
3.60 
>>>CurryPuff(3,'Fish') 
4.2
```

This is something I tried:

```
def CurryPuff(x,typePuff):

   if(typePuff==''):

      return x*1.2

   if(typePuff=='Fish'):

      return x*1.4
```

But it give me this error:

```
TypeError: CurryPuff() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I had try googling on this but I'm not really very sure what is the key word to use, so hopefully can get help from here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can't call a function with 1 argument if it expects 2, as `CurryPuff()` does. However, you can define a default argument that is used if no argument is passed:

```
def CurryPuff(x, typePuff=None):
    if typePuff is None:
       # and so on...
```

You can do this with any value for any argument. You may only omit arguments if a default value is defined.

Comment: +1, but you might want to add that you need to put positional arguments (those without a default value) before any keyword arguments (those with a default value). `def CurryPuff(typePuff=None, x):` would be invalid.

Comment: @Tim I was unaware of this. Thanks for the bit of knowledge.