# NameError: global name 'player' is not defined

Tags: python, python-2.7

Well I am building a PyGame in Sublime text, but when I run the batch file to start it I get this error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "game.py", line 12, in <module>
    player = player("Default", 1, 1, 1)
 File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\RPG\characters\player.py", line 8, in __init__
    Character.__init__(self, name, hp)
 File "C:\Users\*****\Desktop\RPG\characters\character.py", line 9, in  __init__
player.dead = False
NameError: global name 'player' is not defined
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Now here are my files:

game.py file:

---

```
# Main Game File

from characters.player import *
from commands import *

commands = {
    'help': help,
    'exit': exit
 }
player = player("Default", 1, 1, 1)

def isValidCMD(cmd):
    if cmd in commands:
        return True
    return False

def runCMD(cmd, args, player):
    commands[cmd](player, args)

def main(player):
    while(not player.dead):
            line = raw_input(">> ")
        input = line.split()
        input.append("EOI")

        if isValidCMD(input[0]):
            runCMD(input[0], input[1], player)

        main(player)
```

player.py file:

---

```
# Player Base File

from character import *

class player(Character):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, str, int):
        Character.__init__(self, name, hp)
        self.str = str
        self.int = int
```

and the character.py file:

---

```
# Character Base File

class Character(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hp):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp

        player.dead = False

    def attack(self, other):
        pass

    def update(self):
        if self.hp <= 0:
            player.dead = True
            self.hp = 0
```

---

What do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: NameError: global name 'foobar' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068785/python-nameerror-global-name-foobar-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 1):

1) Change

> `from characters.player import *`

to

> `from player import *` in game.py

2)In player.py, `class player` to `class Player`

and

3) in `character.py`, make this change please
from

> `player.dead = False`

to

> `self.dead = False`

Comment: So I changed all of that but it says 'from player import *'

Comment: player is not a module

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a variable with the same name as the package you're trying to access.  Choose something other than **player** for the local variable.

Also, you'll still have a problem within Character.py, as there isn't anything named **player** defined in that file, and no global declared.  I think what you want there is

```
self.dead = False
```

for the Character you're creating.  **player** is a remote class with no **dead** property.

---

You cannot change just the one location: you have to change *all* of the uses for that aspect of the name.  You have used **player** to refer to two different things: (1) a class with attributes **str** and **int** (these are poor names, by the way: there are built-in functions with those names, so these are not distinctive); and (2) a local object that appears to be an instance of class **player**.

There is no good way to use the same name for both.  I suggest something more like

```
pov = player("Grmph the Magnetic", 1, "werewolf", 17)
```

You must also change the other references to the object **player** to be **pov** instead.

---

Also, you seem to be confused by the variety of errors in the current program.  Please consider starting over; use incremental programming.  Write a few lines -- a class definition with its **init** method, and a main program that instantiates and prints a single object.  When that works, add a few lines: some meaningful initialization, perhaps.  Continue adding and testing a few lines at a time until you get back to the level of complexity you have now.

This allows you to seal with only one or two errors at a time.  You're already doing this about half-way, so I don't think it will take long to recover your current level of work ... but with a legal program.

Comment: use player = Player or does it have to be completely different

Comment: **player** is already the name of your class.  You can change either that or the local variable.  Capitalizing one is legal, but poor programming practice.  Make it something descriptive and distinctive in each case.  For instance, make your local variable **pov** or **avatar**, if that suits your mental space.  Also, having things named both **character** and **characters** can lead to confusion.

Comment: so player = Player should be  player = Pov or something like that

Comment: I dont think I quite understand what i need to do entirely