# Name Error not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I wrote the following function:

```
def main_menu(enter_digit):
    Print(a)
    Print(b)
    if enter_digit = 1:
        Print(hello)
        main_menu(1)
```

But it keeps saying `enter_digit` is not defined!

What am I doing wrong? I using the latest Python available.

This is the actual code that I'm running:

```
def Main_menu(Digit):
    print("a - Objective_1")
    print("b - Objective_2")
    print("c - Objective_3")
    print("d - Objective_4")
    print("e - Objective_5")
    print("f - Objective_6")
    print("g - Objective_7")  
    print("h - Exist")
    if Digit == 1:
        print("hello")
        Main_menu(1)
```

But it still says not defined?

Comment: See the edits I made to your code. Note that `=` `!=` `==` ;-). And indentation matters in Python.

Comment: Please don't make edits to answer the question.

Comment: I rolled back changes to the code.

Comment: So many basic errors there.

Comment: Note to OP: Don't feel bad about basic errors. We have all been there.

Comment: I'm aware of the errors of a and b not having "" or not being defined.  I just wrote it like that because, I was using a tablet when I asked this question and I'm a slow typer with it . Thank you though.  I can't believe I didn't notice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: NameError: global name 'foobar' is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068785/python-nameerror-global-name-foobar-is-not-defined)

Comment: @wgwz: I was referring to the fact that those basic syntax errors made it hard to answer the actual question! How do we know which of these errors were also present in the original program and therefore caused the problem?

Comment: @RadLexus you are right, i just wanted to add some encouragement :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def main_menu(enter_digit):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    if enter_digit == 1:
        print(hello)

main_menu(1)
```

The code needed to be indented correctly. Keep in mind that if variables a, hello and b are not defined, the code will not run. If they are not variables, and you want the code to print "hello", "a" and "b", then add quotation marks.

When you were checking the variable value, you were assigning the value, not checking, hence the use of ==.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of a and b I just didn't add "" or define it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Did you forget the inverted commas around hello?

Comment: No I assumed it was a variable. I made a note about this in the answer.

Comment: No it didn't work. I just don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: I left the code above. Sorry I was just testing something.

Comment: What is not defined?

Comment: It keeps saying enter_digit is not defined.

Comment: Is the `if` block inside the function?

Answer (score 0):

The below one will work, its just indentation

```
def Main_menu(Digit):
    print("a - Objective_1")
    print("b - Objective_2")
    print("c - Objective_3")
    print("d - Objective_4")
    print("e - Objective_5")
    print("f - Objective_6")
    print("g - Objective_7")  
    print("h - Exist")
    if Digit == 1:
        print("hello")
Main_menu(1)
```